# VS Go to definition failing / source code not available

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I've just started experimenting with Visual Studio in order to explore F# but I'm never able to navigate to third-party dependencies code through the "Go to definition" option.

I'm getting this error message:

> "Cannot navigate to definition. Source code is not available."

My main language is Java and I'm used to IntelliJ IDEA source retrieval mechanism (usually done through the Maven repositories). I consider this an indispensable functionality when developing code. Isn't there anything similar for .NET?

**EDIT**

After reading the comments and answer, I went looking for some packages on SymbolSource and I found them (e.g. [SymbolSource page for JSON.Net](http://symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Newtonsoft.Json)).

I've tried the PM commands shown and the page but they kept producing errors:

> Install-Package : An error occurred while processing this request.

So I've downloaded NuGet.exe and by running the command in verbose mode I could obtain the URL it was requesting (e.g. [SymbolSource FeedService URL for JSON.Net](http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet/FeedService.mvc/FindPackagesById%28%29?id=%27Newtonsoft.Json%27)).

As you can see it is showing an error:

> Gettting packages from the NuGet feed is temporarily disabled. But you don't need it for debugging!

Is this to be expected?

P.S.: I've also tried with the pre-authenticated links. Same problem.

P.S.2: Seems that I can step into source code of third party dependencies during debug, but I still can't access it through "Go to definition" (neither in Debug nor in Edit mode).

Comment: See http://www.symbolsource.org/Public

Comment: I've already added that previously:

http://i.imgur.com/BriZEzY.png

http://i.imgur.com/i6Vas7E.png

Unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: So maybe the dll doesn't package their source code.

Comment: I doubt so. I've tested with Nancy and JSON.NET which are quite popular open-source projects.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy/

Comment: Go upvote the F12 to metadata issue in the [Visual F# power tools user voice](http://vfpt.uservoice.com/forums/247560-general/suggestions/5737069-f12-navigate-to-metadata) (There is a similar issue with a lot of votes and lots of fragmentation in [the VS uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) too but Visual F# Power Tools seem to be moving pretty fast)

Comment: @RubenBartelink so this is an F# issue?

Comment: An IDE normally decompiles the metadata definition from the reference assembly.  Works fine in the C# and VB.NET IDEs for example.  F# is special though, it is an Open Source project.  Doing the grunt work tends to not be on the top of the list of favorite things to do :)

Comment: @andresp The language specific tooling works out what the type is. Then it performs a source lookup, with a fallback to the metadata and/or Object Browser etc. I'm not particularly familiar with the exact mechanics but I know the suggestion I linked to would give you something when the source isnt there. Having said that, it's not what you asked, sorry :( (But do go upvote anyway!)

Comment: @HansPassant :D In fairness it has to compete with popular stuff like [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2748862-add-create-unit-tests-menu-option-back) and [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2140945-i-wish-catch-multiple-exceptions-in-the-same-catch) which can only be upvoted :(

Comment: @RubenBartelink upvoted. Regarding my problem with the source code, I assume that with my current configuration I should be able to obtain the functionality I'm asking for right?

Comment: Andres, I'll defer to @JohnPalmer on that - he's normally pretty bang on. (And I havent fought a symbol server battle sufficiently recently to recall with confidence ;)

Comment: I've reinstalled VS 2013 Ultimate trial, tested in a new blank C# project and I was only able to get the generated source file from the metadata (the functionality that is apparently missing in F#), but I still couldn't get the source code in C# either.

Comment: So I've went looking for those packages on SymbolSource and I found them (e.g. JSON.Net: https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Newtonsoft.Json ). I've tried the PM commands and got errors ("Install-Package : An error occurred while processing this request."), so I've downloaded NuGet.exe and by running the command in verbose mode I could obtain the URL it was requesting (e.g.: http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet/FeedService.mvc/FindPackagesById%28%29?id=%27Newtonsoft.Json%27 ). As you can see it is showing an error (tbc...)

Comment: "Gettting packages from the NuGet feed is temporarily disabled. But you don't need it for debugging!". Is this expected?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, you might be able to Go to Definition to third-party source code if:

- You are in Debugging mode
- 'Enable source server support' options are turned on (you seem to do that already)
- The third-party assemblies have their pdb files in source servers

Go to Definition in Editing mode doesn't have that capability in either C# or F#. In F#, 'Navigate to Metadata' hasn't been implemented yet.

We haven't been able to add ['Navigate to Source'](http://vfpt.uservoice.com/forums/247560-general/suggestions/5736626-f12-navigate-to-source) to Visual F# Power Tools because they have many tricky issues e.g. (1) The feature is unusable if source server support isn't enabled, which is unfortunate (2) It relies on external data source that might be slow or unavailable (3) There is a good chance that pdb contents are outdated or incorrect, etc.

That said, ['Navigate to Metadata'](http://vfpt.uservoice.com/forums/247560-general/suggestions/5737069-f12-navigate-to-metadata) seems to be less tricky to handle. We have required information from [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service), it requires some effort to filter what we need and present it to users. This feature may be available in a future version of Visual F# Power Tools.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you had to be with the application running and in debug mode for "Go to definition" to work. Why is this so?! Seems rather odd to have to create a working application and run it in order to get access to the best source of documentation (code) to help creating that same application. Nevertheless I've just tried "Go to documentation" when stopped at a breakpoint in a F# application and I got the same error message (tried with constructs from Nancy and JSON.Net packages).